# create-react-app build doen't work in sub directory path

Tags: express, reactjs

create-react-app build is not working in subdirectory on web server.
I’ve used express node web server. ‘create-react-app build’ is working on root directory.But, It doesn’t work on subdirectory.

For example,

localhost/ - It works.
localhost/react-app/ - It doesn’t work.

load related files normally. There are no errors and warnings.
It's look like blank page. Surely I configured ‘homepage field’ in package.json.
I don’t know why this situation occur.
The followings are my configuration.

1. set express for react

   app.get('/*',function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(path.resolve(config.static_root+'/react-app', 'index.html'));
   });
2. add homepage field to package.json

   "homepage": "localhost/react-app"
3. npm run build
4. copy files form build folder and move to /react-app folder.

Comment: Did you type `http://localhost/react-app` into the homepage field? I'm not sure it would get parsed correctly without the protocol.

Comment: con you post your entire package.json?

Comment: I had a similar issue... I used npm init in my main project and ejected my react app into my main project.  You may have a second "homepage" in your package.json overwriting the one think is getting used.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the directory name, or `./` to `package.json`, like so:

`"homepage": "./"`